# r - rmarkdown - render list of dataframes

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is it possible to render a list of data frames in a markdown document as individual tables?

**Example**

Given the code chunk

````
```{r listOfDf}

library(knitr)

df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10),b=rnorm(10),c=c(rep("a",5), rep("b",5)))
l_df <- split(df, df$c)

kable(l_df)

```
````

This outputs

[image: l_df_output]

But I would like something closer to that given in the R console:

```
> l_df
$a
           a          b c
1  1.2869909 -0.3117932 a
2  1.4621792  1.2826924 a
3 -0.4274641  0.3335532 a
4  0.7882973 -1.1966702 a
5 -1.2086910  0.1549691 a

$b
            a         b c
6  -0.9460508 1.4679430 b
7   0.6580554 0.5806850 b
8  -0.7103335 2.6036176 b
9  -2.0110167 2.0488055 b
10  0.7691045 0.3652907 b
```

But that is also rendered as a table(s) (hence the use of `kable()`)

I've tried a loop*

```
for(i in 1:length(l_df)){
  kable(l_df[i])
}
```

but that doesn't work either (*but it does work for graphs)

Comment: just dont use kable?

Comment: @rawr I would also like the output rendered as a table, not just a *print* of the data, hence `kable`

Comment: oh then I would change my comment be use kable like `print(kable(l_df[[i]]))`

Comment: seems like kable is printing the rownames (the answer with pander is doing the same below) when the rownames are *not* 1:n which looks odd to me. You can fix that in your kable option by using `print(kable(\`rownames<-\`(l_df[[i]], NULL)))` or you could do this first `l_df <- lapply(l_df, function(x) \`rownames<-\`(x, NULL))` which will work for either the kable or pander option

Comment: @rawr I went with the `print(kable(l_df[[i]]))` option in the end; thanks for the suggestion. If you want to make it an answer I'll give it a 'tick'

Answer (score 5):

The `pander` package was created to [transform almost any R objects into markdown](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#generic-pander-method). E.g.:

```
> pander(l_df)


  * **a**:

    -------------------------
        a          b       c
    ---------- ---------- ---
    0.5853656  1.3888279   a

    -0.6172632 -0.5179708  a

    -0.3321862 -0.2400778  a

    -0.6503349 0.9474224   a

    0.9476588  0.2288404   a
    -------------------------

  * **b**:

    -------------------------------------
     &nbsp;       a            b       c
    -------- ------------ ----------- ---
     **6**   -0.637650387 0.26547037   b

     **7**   0.233576764  -0.47811415  b

     **8**   -0.283486652 0.61113065   b

     **9**   -0.794994493 -0.08609191  b

     **10**  -0.004526202 0.36841059   b
    -------------------------------------


<!-- end of list -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this function with `{r results='asis'}`

```
affiche_multi_df <- function(b){
  for ( i in seq_along(b)){
    cat(glue::glue("### {names(b)[i]} \n\n"))
    b[[i]] %>%
      DT::datatable() %>%
      htmltools::tagList() %>%
      print()

  }}
```

like this

````
```{r results='asis'} 
list(a=iris,b=iris,c=iris) %>%  affiche_multi_df() 
```
````