# rmarkdown using kable with list of data.tables loses table formatting

Tags: r, r-markdown, tabular, kable

I have a `rmarkdown` document where I want to use a list of `data.table`s and include them in a PDF/HTML/MS Word document. Each component of the list contains one `data.table`.

What I'm trying to achieve is to use `kable` to add all tables in a document with captions.

When I index the `data.table`s one by one like this

````
```{r}
 kable(list.of.dts[[1]], caption = paste0("Frequency table for the '", colnames(list.of.dts[[1]])[2], "' variable."))
```
````

everything is fine and the table is nicely formatted as on the screenshot below.

[image]

However, if I try to use `lapply` to `kable` all the `data.tables` in the list like this

````
```{r}
lapply(X = list.of.dts, FUN = function(i) {
  kable(x = i, caption = paste0("Frequency table for the '", colnames(i)[2], "' variable."))
})
```
````

to process all `data.tables` and include them in the document, I get quite basic and crude output like on the screenshot below.

[image]

Further, if I just pass the list of `data.table`s to `kable` like this

````
```{r}
kable(list.of.dts)
```
````

I get all the tables with a better formatting (although not as in the first example), but stacked on top of each other, centered in the middle of the page and I can't add captions:

[image]

Does anyone know why is this happening and how can I overcome this issue?

**EDIT1:**

I have put `result="asis"` in the chunk of the first example and saved the output to an object, then returned the object and it did the trick:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
my.list2 <- lapply(X = list.of.dts, FUN = function(i) {
  kable(x = i, caption = paste0("Frequency table for the '", colnames(i)[2], "' variable."))
})
my.list2
```
````

If I don't save the output to a new object and then return it, then I get a blank document. The above works (see the screenshot below). The only problems are that I see the names of the list components in between the tables and the tables and their captions are aligned in the middle of the page:

[image]

**EDIT2:**

As user20650 (thank you) noted, explicit loop would work better because none of the list components' names will be shown. Besides that, there is no need to assign the results to a new object and then return it. Here is how it looks:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
for(i in list.of.dts) {
  print(kable(x = i, caption = paste0("Frequency table for the '", colnames(i)[2], "' variable.")))
}
```
````

[image]

The only remaining issue is that the tables are still centered in the page.

**EDIT3**

The last issue (see above) was to align tables and their captions to the left. user20650 made a suggestion that worked for the captions. After I found [this email thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/X_1tpGufN_w), I modified the `yaml` header as follow, adding these `LaTeX` options to the `header-includes:` section:

```
---
title: "My report"
author: "John Doe"
output: pdf_document
toc: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{caption}
  - \captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
  - \usepackage[margins=raggedright]{floatrow}
---
```

The first two lines of `header-includes:` (load the `caption` package and define the cations' settings) fix the captions' position to left. The last line loads the `floatrow` package and and fixes the margins.

Case closed.

Comment: try with a `for` loop (as you are not returning anything, just printing)

Comment: I have a feeling it is due to multiple tables in one expression, if you output the lapply into an object (say `x`) and do `x[[1]]`, `x[[2]]` in the same chunk it outputs both tables separately. Putting in a for loop gives your first result.

Comment: @user20650: Yes, I tried this, following this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317373/r-rmarkdown-render-list-of-dataframes. Does not work even after explicitly wrapping the call to `kable` in `print`, returns the same things as in my second example.

Comment: @panman ; using the example from the link you show: using `for(i in l_df) print( kable(i) )` works for me (also using `results='asis'`). If oyu can't get it to work, can you add a samll reproducible example to your question please.

Comment: @user20650: Thank you! Before I saw your new comment I have update the question. `results='asis'` works with `lapply` too.

Comment: Good stuff. re your edit, if you use an explicit loop, you wont have the list names (that are produced when using lapply)

Comment: @user20650: Thank you for your time and patience! You really helped me a lot, I edited the post again and added the changes. Still, the tables and the captions are centered...

Comment: I take it you are outputting to pdf? if so, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275131/align-caption-to-the-left. So add `header-includes:
   - \usepackage{caption}
   - \captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}` (with correct spacing)

Comment: @user20650: Yes, it is about PDF. Thank you for the suggested code, but it moves only the caption to the left, the tables still remain centered.

Comment: OK, I fixed it and edited the question to leave a paper-trail.

Comment: tl/dr: use `lapply` or `map` with `kable` and add `results='asis'` to chunk options.

Comment: Are you averse to using `pander`?  That's how I approach PDF tabular output.  Also, can we post the solution in the Answer?

Comment: I second @Ben - please post the solution in the Answer section.  It will make it better for future users.