# Printing any number of dataframes stored in list as paged tables in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I often want to print out the dataframes contained in a list as paged tables in my rmarkdown documents. Calling each dataframe individually renders the desired ouptut if the right `df_print` option is selected. However, the point of having a list is that the number of dataframes varies depending on the parameters passed to the rmarkdown document; so that's no real solution.

Based on [Vincent Guyader's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317373/r-rmarkdown-render-list-of-dataframes) and on [this example](https://rstudio.github.io/distill/tables.html) of `rmarkdown::paged_table`, I've tried to do the following without success.

Is there a way to achieve this at all? I'd be happy to use any package that supports pagination remotely resembling the `df_print` option.

````
---
title: "Printing paged tables from a list of dataframes in Rmarkdown"
output: 
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---


```{r}

library(DT)
library(rmarkdown)
library(purrr)
library(knitr)


df_list <- list("cars" = mtcars, "flowers" = iris)


knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, results='asis')

```

### Desired output but impossible to generalise 


```{r}

df_list[["cars"]]

```


```{r}

df_list[["flowers"]]

```

### datatable shows as blanks on the page


```{r}

map(df_list, ~DT::datatable(.x) %>%
      htmltools::tagList() %>%
      print())

```


### rmarkdown outputs dataframe contents as one very long string


```{r}

map(df_list, rmarkdown::paged_table)


```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the JS dependencies needed to render the Datatable are not included in the HTML output. A workaround which I borrowed from [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/273#issuecomment-531254687) is to add a code chunk

````
```{r init-step, include=FALSE}
DT::datatable(mtcars)
```
````

outside of the loop or map statement which ensures that the JS dependencies are included. Also, I would recommend to switch to `purrr::walk` as using `map` has the effect that the tables are plotted twice.

````
---
title: "Printing paged tables from a list of dataframes in Rmarkdown"
output: 
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---


```{r}
library(DT)
library(rmarkdown)
library(purrr)
library(knitr)

df_list <- list("cars" = mtcars, "flowers" = iris)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, results='asis')
```

### Desired output but impossible to generalise 

```{r}
df_list[["cars"]]
```  

```{r}
df_list[["flowers"]] 
```

### datatable shows as blanks on the page

```{r init-step, include=FALSE}
DT::datatable(mtcars)
```  

```{r}
walk(df_list, ~DT::datatable(.x) %>%
      htmltools::tagList() %>%
      print())
```
````

Answer (score 2):

When using `results='asis'` argument, the renderer (here DT) has to be initialized once before being applied on a `asis` list.
This seems to be a general problem, see [here with leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63495651/13513328), and [here with Highcharter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63437006/13513328).

The answer to this general question has been given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63534247/13513328).

In this case:

````
---
title: "Printing paged tables from a list of dataframes in Rmarkdown"
output:
  html_document:
  df_print: paged
---
  
```{r,}

library(DT)
library(rmarkdown)
library(purrr)
library(knitr)


df_list <- list("cars" = mtcars, "flowers" = iris)


knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, results='asis')
# initialize the renderer
data.frame() %>%
  DT::datatable() %>%
  knitr::knit_print() %>%
  attr('knit_meta') %>%
  knitr::knit_meta_add() %>%
  invisible()

```


```{r , results='asis'}
#Remove already printed element and print the rest
df_list[[1]] <- NULL

map(df_list, ~DT::datatable(.x) %>%
      htmltools::tagList() %>%
      print())

```
````

Comment: Hi @Waldi did you every follow this up as I'm running into a similar issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64430375/) except in my case I don't have a list of plots so I can't just print the first element of my list to load the renderer.